# PHP - How to split MVC - View (using e.g. non logic templating engine) into logic class and raw html template?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks, templating

I am convinced that templates should not contain any logic just {  }  and include and block parts thats all. In MVC frameworks V is usually raw php mixed with HTML which is IMO very bad for someone used to clean HTML and for designers a nightmare. But putting view logic inside controller is also a wrong approach.

I would like to know how to make it like this. 
Request -> Controller -> load model... logic send everything to -> View -> view logic blocks... -> template

Is this possible in frameworks like Laravel or Fuelphhp? Or more generally is this even a good practise?

Comment: Try some PHP micro-framework like [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), which allows you to use templates ([Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) in this case).

Comment: View files should not contain any *business* logic but there's no reason (or point) for avoiding any logic at all.

Comment: As a personal aside, I like PHPTAL - which encapsulates template logic inside the HTML tags as attributes; it's designer-friendly as well.

Comment: Btw, technically views can connect straight to the model as well (i.e. without controller in between)

Answer (score 3):

Very generally: many PHP frameworks implement "View" not very well. Nothing says that the view needs to be *only* a template file or that it needs to be a template at all. The view is the piece of code that visualizes the model data. That can be as complex or simple as it needs to be. It can be a class that returns JSON, or binary data, or anything else. It does not need to involve HTML at all.

If it does involve HTML, there's nothing that says the controller needs to basically set all variables, then `include` the HTML template. That's too little. A view should be an independent piece of code, likely a class, that does whatever it needs to do to visualize a certain piece of data or object. A view can consist of more than one class. There can be a whole layer of logic in the view before any HTML template is even loaded from disk. Do what makes the most sense in your app.

Answer (score 3):

View is the part of MVC which is responsible for presentation logic. A properly written view will acquire information from model layer and, based on this information, decide what response the user should get.

If view is tasked with creating HTML response, it would use combination of multiple [templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html)  (archived version: https://archive.md/CiHhD) to create it. Or maybe it might just send a HTTP header back to the browser.

In a different situation view might be just generating JSON for REST API or XML for SOAP.

But in all those cases view decides how to represent the information. Controller is only responsible for changing the state of model layer and current view.

### P.S.

MVC itself is a design pattern, which is made up from two layers: presentation layer and model layer. Model layer deals with all of the domain business logic, while presentation - with user interface and interaction.

There is no such thing as "controller layer" or "view layer".

There is a simple reason why most of the Rails clones insist that view is a template and call ORM as "model". Those framework are created for rapid prototyping (generation of *throw-away* code) and NOT maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of your sentiments above...

Logic does not belong in views... **Unless** it is view logic directly related to that particular view. Allowing some basic logic prevents a class explosion where you try to work around your own rules as to what a view should be. The bottom line rule is that views should happen at the end of the request and only read / query the model. Avoid duplication by moving logic into classes.

View logic does not belong in the controller... Mainly because it is easy to tangle things up, the controller makes changes to the model and then invokes the view process.

Generally you should organise your work based upon a controller layer which handles incoming input and modifies the model and a view layer which renders the model.

Most frameworks and raw PHP can be used to adhere to this ethic.